# Issues with Flutter state

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-state, statelesswidget

**This is an experiment with Flutter**. I was trying to create a paragraph generator in Flutter. Made a UI

[image]

Loaded the data from a `List<String>`.

`data.dart`

```
class MyData {
  static final List<String> data1 = [
    '0Title Of Page',
    '3Paragraph title One',
    '1First Paragraph Content Of Page',
    '3Paragraph title two',
    '1Second Paragraph Content Of Page',
    '4End of the page line',
  ];
}
```

I wanted to take the first item from this list to the title of the `AppBar()`, and it worked. Then I wanted to remove the first item (which is used as the `AppBar` title) from this list and carry on with the rest of the items in the list to build the `body:` of the UI.

This works fine when we open this page for the first time. From the next time on, we lose the first item from the list each time we open and close the page. Even though the pages are `StatelessWidget` we lose the items and finally list running out of items.

**Things I tried:**

- I tried changing pages and widgets to `StatelessWidget`.
- Tried to `override` the `AppBar` back button and `pop()` the page.
- Copied `List<String>` to a new varriable.
- Used the `dispose()` method.

Still the same happens. What may be the issues? adding the code below.

`main.dart`

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'home_page.dart';
import 'page_one.dart';
import 'page_two.dart';
void main() => runApp(MyApp());
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Paragraph Test',
      initialRoute: '/',
      routes: {
        '/': (context) => HomePage(),
        '/pageone': (context) => PageOne(),
        '/pagetwo': (context) => PageTwo(),
      },
    );
  }
}
```

`home_page.dart`

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'button.dart';
class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Page Test'),
      ),
      body: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
        children: <Widget>[
          CButton(
            onTap: () {
              Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/pageone');
            },
            text: 'Page One',
          ),
          CButton(
            onTap: () {
              Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/pagetwo');
            },
            text: 'Page Two',
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

`page_one.dart`

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'data.dart';
var weight = FontWeight.normal;
var align = TextAlign.center;
var color = Colors.white60;
var size = 16.0;
String x, y;
class PageOne extends StatelessWidget {
  buildText(String b) {
    x = b.substring(0, 1);
    y = b.substring(1);
    if (x.contains('0')) {
      weight = FontWeight.bold;
      color = Colors.blue;
      size = 18.0;
      align = TextAlign.center;
    } else if (x.contains('2')) {
      weight = FontWeight.normal;
      color = Colors.blue;
      align = TextAlign.right;
      size = 16.0;
    } else if (x.contains('3')) {
      weight = FontWeight.normal;
      color = Colors.blue;
      align = TextAlign.center;
      size = 16.0;
    } else if (x.contains('4')) {
      weight = FontWeight.normal;
      color = Colors.red;
      align = TextAlign.center;
      size = 16.0;
    } else {
      weight = FontWeight.normal;
      color = Colors.white60;
      align = TextAlign.center;
      size = 16.0;
    }
    return y;
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    String title = MyData.data1.first.substring(1);
    MyData.data1.removeAt(0);
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        centerTitle: true,
        title: Text('$title'),
      ),
      body: Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: Colors.blueGrey,
        ),
        child: Container(
          width: double.infinity,
          height: double.infinity,
          margin: EdgeInsets.all(
            12.0,
          ),
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: Color(0x99000000),
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
          ),
          child: SingleChildScrollView(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            child: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
              children: MyData.data1
                  .map(
                    (item) => Text(
                      buildText(item),
                      textAlign: align,
                      style: TextStyle(
                        color: color,
                        fontWeight: weight,
                        fontSize: size,
                      ),
                    ),
                  )
                  .toList(),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        child: Text('Page 1'),
        onPressed: () {},
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

`page_two.dart`

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'data.dart';
var weight = FontWeight.normal;
var align = TextAlign.center;
var color = Colors.white60;
var size = 16.0;
String x, y;
class PageTwo extends StatelessWidget {
  buildText(String b) {
    x = b.substring(0, 1);
    y = b.substring(1);
    if (x.contains('0')) {
      weight = FontWeight.bold;
      color = Colors.blue;
      size = 18.0;
      align = TextAlign.center;
    } else if (x.contains('2')) {
      weight = FontWeight.normal;
      color = Colors.blue;
      align = TextAlign.right;
      size = 16.0;
    } else if (x.contains('3')) {
      weight = FontWeight.normal;
      color = Colors.blue;
      align = TextAlign.center;
      size = 16.0;
    } else if (x.contains('4')) {
      weight = FontWeight.normal;
      color = Colors.red;
      align = TextAlign.center;
      size = 16.0;
    } else {
      weight = FontWeight.normal;
      color = Colors.white60;
      align = TextAlign.center;
      size = 16.0;
    }
    return y;
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    String title = MyData.data1.first.substring(1);
    MyData.data1.removeAt(0);
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        centerTitle: true,
        title: Text('$title'),
      ),
      body: Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: Colors.blueGrey,
        ),
        child: Container(
          width: double.infinity,
          height: double.infinity,
          margin: EdgeInsets.all(
            12.0,
          ),
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: Color(0x99000000),
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
          ),
          child: SingleChildScrollView(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            child: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
              children: MyData.data1
                  .map(
                    (item) => Text(
                      buildText(item),
                      textAlign: align,
                      style: TextStyle(
                        color: color,
                        fontWeight: weight,
                        fontSize: size,
                      ),
                    ),
                  )
                  .toList(),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        child: Text('Page 2'),
        onPressed: () {},
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

`button.dart`

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
class CButton extends StatelessWidget {
  CButton({this.text, this.onTap});
  final String text;
  final Function onTap;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: onTap,
      child: Container(
        margin: EdgeInsets.all(2.0),
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.blue),
        child: Text(
          '$text',
          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: it is happening because you are removing items from your list during `build`. As build runs everytime you come into this screen, your list gets empty. The error in your screenshot comes when using `list.first` on an empty list.

Comment: @Ryosuke but, the page's build function should lose its state while closing the page right? so when we come back to this page it should be rebuilding and getting a new data list? why is the page not building with a fresh data list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`data1` is `static` variable in `MyData` class. So its kind of global variable with namespace `MyData`. So every time you do `MyData.data1.removeAt(0);` will affect the same memory(or object).

For your case try this,

```
class MyData {
  static List<String> get data1 => [
    '0Title Of Page',
    '3Paragraph title One',
    '1First Paragraph Content Of Page',
    '3Paragraph title two',
    '1Second Paragraph Content Of Page',
    '4End of the page line',
  ];
}
```

```
class PageOne extends StatelessWidget {
  buildText(String b) {
    x = b.substring(0, 1);
    y = b.substring(1);
    if (x.contains('0')) {
      weight = FontWeight.bold;
      color = Colors.blue;
      size = 18.0;
      align = TextAlign.center;
    } else if (x.contains('2')) {
      weight = FontWeight.normal;
      color = Colors.blue;
      align = TextAlign.right;
      size = 16.0;
    } else if (x.contains('3')) {
      weight = FontWeight.normal;
      color = Colors.blue;
      align = TextAlign.center;
      size = 16.0;
    } else if (x.contains('4')) {
      weight = FontWeight.normal;
      color = Colors.red;
      align = TextAlign.center;
      size = 16.0;
    } else {
      weight = FontWeight.normal;
      color = Colors.white60;
      align = TextAlign.center;
      size = 16.0;
    }
    return y;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final data1 = MyData.data1;
    String title = data1.first.substring(1);
    data1.removeAt(0);
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        centerTitle: true,
        title: Text('$title'),
      ),
      body: Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: Colors.blueGrey,
        ),
        child: Container(
          width: double.infinity,
          height: double.infinity,
          margin: EdgeInsets.all(
            12.0,
          ),
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: Color(0x99000000),
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
          ),
          child: SingleChildScrollView(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            child: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
              children: data1
                  .map(
                    (item) => Text(
                      buildText(item),
                      textAlign: align,
                      style: TextStyle(
                        color: color,
                        fontWeight: weight,
                        fontSize: size,
                      ),
                    ),
                  )
                  .toList(),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        child: Text('Page 1'),
        onPressed: () {},
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Okay, that worked. 
This has nothing to do with the State of the widgets or app?

Comment: Yes. And there is no state in `Stateless` widget

Comment: whats that `get` key word for?

Comment: @AbyMathew it is an keyword to define a getter function. with this you can just do `var x = getter`  instead of `var x = getter()`.